# Xtext: Run features like validation on demand

Tags: validation, highlight, xtext, markers

Some introduction:
I'm writing a plugin that uses Xtext. This plugin opens the Xtext's Eclipse and when the user clicks a button on this eclipse, my plugin computes something on the INode-s. 
Then, given some INode list, I want to highlight (underline + markers) the lines corresponding to the INodes **without re-running the eclipse**.

I think the best way to do it is to call a specific validator (if not possible, re-running all of the validators is fine too) on demand. 
How can I tell Xtext to run the validator after it's already been launched?

Another way I thought of was using SemanticHighlight for a given INodes list. But it's probably the same problem as above.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "without re-running the eclipse"? Are you restarting your whole Eclipse workbench every time you change the file?

Comment: No I don't restart. I mean that I want to re-run validators (for example) from the plugin code, without any special action from the client (closing and opening the tab of the file, restarting the eclipse etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xtext validation is usually integrated in the Eclipse build process and thus no user action is required as long as automatic build is enabled.  Please refer to http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/303_runtime_concepts.html#custom-validation

If you *really* need access to the Node Model (i.e. INode), you can access it using NodeModelUtils.findActualNodeFor(EObject)